# Cannot Link TextField to IBOutlet Variable

Tags: ios, uitextfield, iboutlet

I have declared the IBOutlet variables that I want to hook up to my UI views like this in the header file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *bookName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *author;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *description;

@end
```

But when I ctrl-click from the View controller to the UI, I don't see the variables show up in the pop-up menu to be selected for linking. I see this:

[image]

But I expect to see the entire list of outlets

Comment: please check the controllers class has been assigned or not ??

Comment: @shujatAli Sorry what do you mean by assigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please check controllers class as shown in snapshot. it should point to current viewcontroller

To open this panel select your controller from story board press cmd+option+0
[image: viewcontorller]

Answer (score 0):

Ok Firstly make sure that your xib's file owner is the viewcontroller you want it to be associated with like this.[image]

One way to see the entire list is here. You can drag and connect the outlets. This is after you have set the file owner.

[image]

A note. You have not yet connected the viewcontrollers view to the xib in the screenshot of your question. Hope this helps.